# What do I need to promote someone to Taekwondo dan rank under the Kukkiwon?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, grading

What are the rules set by the Kukkiwon on who can promote others to black belt ranks (Dan for 15 years old and over, Poom for under 15 years old)?

Can individual instructors do it?

Comment: Wigwam, who is currently downvoted at -1. He is completely correct pursuant to the new rules for Dan promotion written as of May 2016. Downvote him all you want, or go and read the new regulations, because his information is 100% correct and spot on

Comment: Great, can you cite a reference for this? For example http://www.kukkiwon.or.kr/english/examination/examination08.jsp doesn't state anything about "At a minimum, three to ten people must promote" nor the requirement to be a "A Kukkiwon-certified instructor" nor "6th dan or higher". Again, I'm happy to change my understanding, I regularly attend Kukkiwon courses to try to ensure I'm up to date - but I'd need a reference to the correct information not just the opinion of "some guy off the internet".

Comment: If you're referring to http://www.kukkiwon.or.kr/front/pageView.action?cmd=/eng/evaluate/regulations then remember these only apply to MNAs that run open dan testing, and don't apply to individual master instructors recommending their own students after dan testing.

Comment: In the link, Article 6, bullet 3 indicates "(3) Promotion tests should be composed of three to ten members and they must be arranged so that they may easily view the testee's performance".  Article 1 and 2 explain the 6th dan qualifications (now 7th).  But no mention is made about open testing - even in tests which appear to be private still adhere to these guidelines - number of instructors, rank, paperwork, age and time... all of it.  Facility features is usually what is not always optimal.  And I've never seen a doctor present.

Comment: I get what you say about MNA, and such is described in that context in the links.  But there is no mention of how to apply for dan certification outside of MNA, except where MNA is not available in countries - hardly meant to describe private dojangs.  There is the notable exception in article 6.2 "Any Member National Association which does not have, among its members, official Kukkiwon 6th Dan or higher Dan holders should obtain approval from the Kukkiwon to carry out the testing." and that suggests where we could both be correct - and which introduces the exceptions

Comment: And the exceptions are that individual masters of 4th Dan or above can promote their own students without needing a panel, all they need to do is apply to be a KMS member. Source: Poom/Dan Examiner Course Austria 2015 ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The Kukkiwon splits all the countries in the world into two categories, depending on whether that Member National Association (MNA) for the World Taekwondo Federation (WTF) in that country controls over 70% of Taekwondo groups and instructors.  Those that do are considered to be in the "1st Category" and recommendations can only be made by the President of the MNA in that country.  South Korea is a good example of a 1st Category country.

In countries outside of that category, the Kukkiwon requires instructors to be a 4th Dan or above.  They encourage all instructors to register with their [Kukkiwon Membership System](http://kms.kukkiwon.or.kr/usr/main.do) and process the dan applications online.  Dan applications can be done up to one grade below the instructor's rank, except for 8th/9th Dan which must be taken at the Kukkiwon in South Korea.

Instructors meeting this criteria can also test students for coloured belt ranks (Kup) and can process Dan Assimilation requests (crossing over Taekwondo Dan from another organisation) and Single Jump Dan requests (where a person has had sufficient time in grade to have achieved two dan grades higher than they are now, they can be tested for the higher rank and pay for both).  Multiple Jump dan (where they have time in grade to be three or more ranks higher) can only be tested for at the Kukkiwon or at a Kukkiwon Special Dan test.

The Kukkiwon doesn't allow instructors below 4th Dan to test anyone for rank.

Source: [Kukkiwon regulations](http://www.kukkiwon.or.kr/english/examination/examination08.jsp), Kukkiwon Master Training Course (2013), Kukkiwon Poom/Dan Examiner Course (2015), Kukkiwon Master Training Course (2016)

Comment: Please note - there are changes coming in next year that will change this - with a lot of anger at the new rules from a lot of the international community.

Comment: Considering that you edited this 2 years after your initial comment, does the comment still apply?

Answer (score 2):

In tae kwon do, the rules are simple. You must be at least an instructor, and you must be at least 1 degree above the rank you are testing your student to. For example. I am a 5th Dan, therefore I can test a student up to 4th Dan, but before that student may test to 5th Dan, you must either have a 6th Dan, or higher at a minimum watching your testing and certifying that your student has met the requirements to pass the test.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot typically test an applicant alone.  At a minimum, three to ten people must promote.  Read on:

**They must be**:

- A Kukkiwon-certified instructor
- 6th dan or higher

**There must be**:

- The 3-10 members to oversee the test, which may or may not include you
- A place to conduct the test, in accordance with KKW regulations

  - If testing < 6th dan, you can do it locally
  - If testing >= 6th dan, you do it at a certified WTF facility
- A doctor on-hand

**You must be**:

- Able to submit your student's application to your member national association (in the US, that would be Team USA Taekwondo, and you'd submit the application to the president's office, currently is Keith Ferguson who is executive director.  It is likely he'll refer you to your state association.  In my case, that would be in NJ, and the contact is Kevin Vigneri)

[USA Taekwondo](http://www.teamusa.org/usa-taekwondo)

[US State Associations](http://www.teamusa.org/usa-taekwondo/v2-membership/state-associations)

---

**Student must be**:

- Within age and time guidelines

**Student must do**:

- Perform:

  - poomsae (forms) - which ones depend on dan test
  - kyrogi (sparring)
  - kyukpa (breaking) - power
  - special techniques (fancy kicks, self-defense, creative form, creative breaking... whatever instructors want)
- Depending on the dan test, may have written exam and/or submit thesis
- Pass a health examination by doctor
- Score 60% or better in each category, by majority of test overseers

---

**Alternatives**:

There are other ways to promote a student in Kukkiwon, or have TeamUSA recognize your student as a dan rank.

If your student is a dan rank in the styles of ITF (International Taekwondo Federation) or ATA (American Taekwondo Association), then, that student may fill out paperwork and send (with $50) to the US National Dan Program, which will attest to your student's dan rank, and allow your student to be recognized up to 4th dan for purposes of WTF-sanctioned event competition.  This is not Kukkiwon-recognized, and, WTF schools may choose not to accept this; however, the individual may still compete in WTF events (except, not Olympics).  This alternative is only available in the USA, however other countries may have similar alternatives.

If your student is a dan rank in Kukkiwon-overseen styles, such as from fraternal Kwan organizations (eg, Chung Do Kwan), or from Tang Soo Do organizations, or from a school not run by a Kukkiwon certified instructor, then there is a special administrative process to get your dan rank from that organization or school to transfer to Kukkiwon.

---

**Note**:
There are always exceptions, and that depends on your instructor's involvement with TeamUSA, WT, Kukkiwon, rank, and other criteria.  That is why this alternative exists:

Your student can also do it by him/herself, online.  There are some online methods (for example, http://www.taekwonwoo.net) for attaining dan rank.  While I think this is a scam, it is legitimate, and because of the way Kukkiwon and WTF work world-wide, such a student would have to be accepted... everywhere.

While this last option is a gross affront to those who have to go through the gauntlet everyone else has to go through, there is nothing stopping you (as an instructor) from coaching your protege through this online process.  This makes the concept of online promotion a little easier to go down than castor oil, especially if you have a talented student but who has no means to go through the traditional means of attaining dan rank.

Comment: This is incorrect. The requirements above regarding panels and requirements ("They must be" and "There must be") are proposed changes for *if* the new Dan/Poom Examiner requirements go through. They are also incorrect if you're testing your own student. I specifically asked two Poom/Dan Examiner Course instructors from Kukkiwon about this on the Examiner Course in Austria 2015. If you're testing your own student. Currently it's Kukkiwon 4th Dan upwards can test, must be a KMS member (free to join). Going forward it's Kukkiwon examiner certificate required, but still can test own students.

Comment: I stand by my answer.  These rules have been in place for years.  It doesn't mean the rules aren't overlooked - they certainly are from time to time.  Especially for some well-respected members in the community.  In fact, it seems rampant - and getting worse.  But I can't ethically provide an answer based on what everyone else is doing, when the official documents, which have been around for years, say otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say these rules have been in place for years. There's no documentation of these rules on the Kukkiwon site. If you believe official documents exist, please show them. You've given links to USA websites (and those may be the rules in USA), but the question was asked about Kukkiwon (global) rules. I've attended the Master Instructor course and Poom/Dan Examiner course (certificates on my website at https://www.stevenagetaekwondo.co.uk/instructors) and I've promoted many people to black belt and beyond without needing a panel (or ever being told I needed one).

Comment: Even USAT's Dan Promotion Guidelines (http://go.teamusa.org/2wERdNl) say "1.4. Those testing for 1st through 3rd Dan must test with their current Instructor." - no mention of a panel, no mention of a 6th Dan minimum for the examiner. Certainly no mention of a "certified WTF facility" - what the heck even is that, there are no certified WTF facilities, the WT (ex. WTF) is the "International Federation (IF) governing the sport of Taekwondo" http://worldtaekwondo.org/about-wt/about-wt/ and has nothing to do with Dan promotions. Again, please cite your sources or this is just your opinion of rules

Comment: "There's no documentation of these rules on the Kukkiwon site." Yes, there certainly is.  Here is the link, it is the official Kukkiwon site.

http://www.kukkiwon.or.kr/front/pageView.action?cmd=/eng/evaluate/regulations

Comment: Article 6, 5th bullet:
Those who have acquired an instructor certificate of 4th Dan and above may make recommendations for Poom or Dan promotion below their level.

Comment: Article 11:
Must be 6th dan or higher, must have 3 to 5 (not 10, a recent change), and can be adjusted based on testing features

Comment: Article 15: Testing facility
The overall facility requirements for a testing place shall be set forth as follows pursuant to Article 8-②-2 of Test Regulations:
1. A testing place shall be a minimum of 15 meters in width by 12 meters in length (approximately 180 square meters).
2. The area for a Poomsae testing place for one session shall be a minimum of 20 square meters per person, 60 square meters for three individuals, 90 square meters for five individuals and 170 square meters for nine individuals.

Comment: ...3. A testing place for Kyorugi (Sparring) for two persons shall be a minimum of 10 meters in width by 10 meters in length.
4. A testing place for Kyokpa and special techniques shall be a minimum of 20 square meters per person.
5. For a smooth promotion test, at least 33 square meters must be secured for a waiting place for each testing subject.
6. The flooring of a practical testing place shall be comprised of elastic cover and a rubber mat.
7. A testing place shall be a fire-proof and disaster-proof area, where safety is guaranteed for the welfare of applicants.

Comment: I said before, I say again: I stand by my answer.  I also stated that there are exceptions, and there are many - even egregious ones.  Most of the time, I think, the exceptions are given in deference to those who are held in high regard, and they are often entrusted to help keep backlog away from Kukkiwon and their procedures - a huge complaint years ago.  Yes, there are rules, and yes, there are exceptions.  I posted the official rules, and I stand by them.

Comment: I've been following these guidelines for at least 12 years since I've been on testing committees.  I don't know if, or how long, they've been in place before that.

Comment: Have you attended the poom/dan examiner course? I did and recorded audio of one Kukkiwon instructor answering exactly this question (and had a very well respected international coach be witness to a different instructor saying the same thing). Those committees described in the regulations are for if you're running an open dan testing exam (to stop bias against other dojang's students). If you are testing your own students then only Article 6's rule applies. Anyway, we're not going to agree on this, so I'll stop here. There's lots of good information here either way for visitors to read.

Comment: Ok fair enough.  The idea that these articles were meant for open testing never came up, perhaps you are right.  And, no - I never did attend a formal seminar.  It's on my life's bucket list though

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't recommend the Poom/Dan Examiner Course (unless it's changed a lot in the last two years), but the Master Instructor Course is really good. I kept diaries of all three on my blog if you're interested in the read... https://www.andyjeffries.co.uk/

Comment: I have an opportunity to take a master instructor course here in NJ in November.  Here's a link: https://www.wtmu.org/kukkiwon-courses  I don't know anything about the organization, the flier came to me via spam email.  It caught my interest, but I'd have to take two days off work, and anyway, it conflicts with a scouting trip.  But I'm told these things happen all the time, so maybe I can catch another one somewhere else nearby.  Thank you for the link, I'll check them out.

Comment: did you take the master instructor and poom/dan examiner course? Did you get clarification? If not, I can speak to Kukkiwon directly and ask them for a quotable answer.

Comment: No, I didn't get a chance to go; there's another WTMU course offered in December in Illinois this year, and I won't make that either.  But I've had opportunity to ask, all are aware of this ruling and explain them as reasons to reduce the appearance of impropriety.  They say formal testing is generally demanded.  They also note nothing in these rules make distinction of open or private testing and that these rules apply to all, and try to make testing across the board consistent.  Olympics is taken seriously, no need to risk someone's career with suggestions of cheating on advancement.

Comment: This I cannot source, of course; but the reasons are logical.  What is important is to note that nothing in the articles make any mention of open testing.  Everyone I've ever asked has applied these standards for all of their tests.  All testing is treated exactly the same.  (Noting there are always exceptions, such as online testing - and I don't know how this is circumvented, except that the videos themselves provide proof of performance.)

Comment: All I know is what we were told at the poom/dan examiner course in 2015 (and Master course in 2016) and that we can recommend poom/dan up to one below ourselves (up to 7th Dan) without needing a panel of judges. I've personally promoted someone to Kukkiwon 5th Dan this year.

Comment: Also "Olympics is taken seriously" - in the UK the national team will pretty much give anyone a 1st Dan so they can compete, and they openly recruit from all other martial arts in the UK to the national team. I'm completely against this practice, but it happens and that case the Olympics (and the funding that goes with it) is the reason for not following Kukkiwon rules rather than the reason for the rules existing.

Comment: I absolutely agree, and I think the exceptions are rampant.  There is no doubt tons cronyism going on in our industry; I was promoted all the way up to 3rd dan from a 5th dan, but, he knew someone who knew someone, and with computers, I guess it's easy to push a few buttons to get things done.

Comment: Just to be clear though, I don't think the perfectly legal/valid exceptions are a bad thing. I test all of my students for dan rank and to a much higher standard than in our official WT MNA. The syllabus is more extensive and is up to date with current Kukkiwon standards (e.g. how one-step sparring should be done now). The Kukkiwon also wants instructors to make allowances for people with disabilities or other individual problems, that's hard to do for a panel that doesn't know the candidate. So I don't think testing outside of panels is a bad thing at all.